# Spring RESTful, error returning JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, rest

i'm encountering an error while producing JSON from DAO, here is my code

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/findAdpId/", method=RequestMethod.POST , consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody AllCustomerHist findAdpId(@RequestBody AllCustomerHist customer){
    String customerId = customer.getCustomerId();
    String srctable = customer.getSrctable();

    System.out.println("customer ID = "+customerId);
    System.out.println("srctable = "+srctable);
    List<AllCustomerHist> adpcust = allCustomerHistService.findAdpId(customerId, srctable);
    return (AllCustomerHist) adpcust;       
}
```

DAO Class

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<AllCustomerHist> findAdpId(String customerId, String srctable) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(AllCustomerHist.class)
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.property("adpId"), "adpId"))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("customerId", customerId))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("srctable", srctable));

    return (List<AllCustomerHist>)criteria.list();
}
```

what i want is, when retrieving JSON like

```
{
"customerId":"11",
"srctable":"transaction"
}
```

my DAO class will produce

```
{
"adpId":["abcd123","defw123"]
}
```

this is the error log

> Exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to
>   com.astra.adp.model.AllCustomerHist
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> Root Cause
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to
>   com.astra.adp.model.AllCustomerHist
>
> com.astra.adp.controller.CustomerController.findAdpId(CustomerController.java:73)
>
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
>
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>
> Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server
>   logs.

thank you for the helps!

Comment: What is the error you face at this moment? What is the result your code produces? What does `AllCustomerHist` look like? Are you aware that in your controller you are trying to cast `List<AllCustomerHist>` to `AllCustomerHist` which definitely causes `ClassCastException`? You should pick list element instead of casting a list to an object.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak edited, AllCustomerHist is an entity class, where can i pick list elemen? in the DAO class? or in the controller?

Comment: In the controller you are calling a method that returns `List<AllCustomerHist>`, but this controller method returns `AllCustomerHist`. And this is why you see this `ClassCastException` in the first place. You can do two things: a) call DAO method that returns single `AllCustomerHist` or pick some element (I don't know which one) from the list and return it, b) change your controller method signature and return `List<AllCustomerHist>` instead, without any change to your controller method implementation.

Comment: got it, solved, i cannot use List element, so i changed method return type to string and build JSON array key and value (result from query) using jsonobject